# Keep dropdown menu open after page refresh

Tags: javascript, html, drop-down-menu, dropdown

There is a form inside my dropdown menu for logging in. If the user submits that form but the login details were wrong the page get refreshed and the dropdown menu closes. How do i keep the dropdown menu in an open state after refresing that page?

Comment: you need to use SessionStorage for it. Alternativly LocalStorage but then it will always keep open even if you close the browser. https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage

Comment: share the code , Button `type='submit'` will refresh if you have method attribute in form

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, I would check to see if there is a way to submit the form without a page refresh, by making the request asynchronously and prevent the default behavior of a page refresh.
So in your form submit, you can just do:
`event.preventDefault()`
And then handle the request asynchronously. That way, you will preserve your state.

But if you really need to do a page refresh for some reason, then I would perhaps use Local Storage for that. So, you can store some flag in the browser's local storage which checks to see if the drop down was in an open state, like:
`localStorage.setItem('dropdownWasOpen', 'true');`

And then whenever the page is refreshed, you read from the local storage again with `localStorage.getItem('dropdownWasOpen')`.

Comment: How do i check if the drop down was in an open state? I tryed but i could not figure it out.

Comment: Please share your code in a JSFiddle so I can see the actual scenario. If you want to persist the state, you should avoid making a page refresh. Because if the page is refreshed, then it's not easy to "programmatically" open the dropdown for the user again. 

The easiest way is to simply submit the form asynchronously with JavaScript, and prevent the default behavior. Also, I'm not sure if the dropdown is a native HTML select, or if it's a custom-made dropdown.

Comment: Managed to get away with the other one, just a bit of a twisting was required from my part. Marked is an answer!

Comment: Glad you fixed it :)